# Typescript: setting a property to be a particular type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm very new to Typescript, just exploring how to convert our existing JS code.  My approach (which may well be flawed) is to do the minimal to just get it working in TypeScript, and then gradually convert it to follow "best practices".

I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.....

I have the following TypeScript, using jQuery (in an ASP.NET .NET5 application).

```
interface MyInterface {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

const something = {
    currentThing : MyInterface,

    init: (): void => {
        //
    }
};

$(something.init);
```

So the idea is that when the page loads, `something.init` will be executed.  This will set up things like event handlers *via* jQuery selectors, *etc*. *etc*.  All that part seems to work just fine.

However...

At some point, an event handler will fire and I'll create a new object that will implement `MyInterface`.  I'll need to preserve that (by setting it to be the value of the property/field `currentThing`) so that it can then be accessed by future events.

However, Typescript doesn't like the line `currentActivity: MyInterface,` and I get the error:

> 'MyInterface' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: You cannot assign types to properties inside an object literal. You need to assign a type *for* that `something` object, for example like `const something: { currentThing: MyInterface, init: () => void } = { /* ... */}`. It's also probably a good idea to extract that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object follows the key-value structure, Typescript understands the current object definition as

```js
const something = {
    //    key         value
    currentThing : MyInterface,    
};
```

and as `MyInterface` is not a valid value, it will throw the mentioned error.

What you should do in this case is to define types for the `something` object, typing its properties like the following:

```js
interface MyInterface {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

interface SomethingInterface {
    currentThing : MyInterface;
    init: () => void
}

const currentThing = { prop1: 'aStringValue', prop2: 12345 };
const something: SomethingInterface = {
    currentThing,
    init: (): void => {
        //
    }
};

$(something.init);
```

Comment: I tried the above (which works) but with the following adaption.  I'd like to hear whether my adaption is seen as good practice or not...  I changed from `const currentThing = { prop1: 'aStringValue', prop2: 12345 };` to `const currentThing: MyInterface = null;` as I wasn't keen on creating a dummy object.  I also wasn't sure whether this ought to be a `const`...  Within the `init` function I could set it using `something.currentThing = { prop1: "abc", prop2: 12345 };` and retrieve it later.

Comment: Have you considered to use a `class`? You could replace the `init()` to be a `constructor()` and then call `$(new Something(currentThing))`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to type your `something` object using a new interface, [like](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=18&pln=11&pc=27#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkAHKAe3IEYAuZAZzClAHMBuEsymgJkYgArgFsARtG4BfIkVCRYiFAGUqoiGAAWHQjwTCoUCOAAqOkO0YZsivBG6lQwMIwAUASmQBeAHzIANypgABMZOQQqEBZmdU0LK2Q1DW1dbz0yZAMjEzBzDkZiTNI+OkYAchgqKnKAGh5M0sFkAFZ6zOl6huRnV2RPRiDQn38i4tIAegnu2WluIkjoqgAbCAA6Zap2NyY41Ms13o9OIA) :

```
interface MyInterface {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

interface Something {
  currentThing: MyInterface;
  init: () => void;
}

const something: Something = {
    currentThing: {
      prop1: 'foo',
      prop2: 5,
    },

    init: (): void => {
        //
    },
};

console.log(something.init);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you cannot use typings for fields inside an object literal. If necessary I make it more readable using a class instead and export a const using the instance of that class.

Example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

class Something implements MyInterface {

    public Something(public prop1: string, public prop2: number) {
    }

    init(): void {
    }
}

export const something = new Something('value1', 10);

$(something.init);
```